# getting each tag name of a "tags" element of a xml response is not working

Tags: python, xml

Im getting the top artists from a specific country and then I want to store the name and tags of each artist.The name is working fine but the tags its not working. The tags are the genre like rock, jazz and so on.

Part where im getting the tags:

```
for child in tree:
    for artist in child:
        print(artist)
        for tag in artist.findall('tags'):
            print(tag)
            bands[i]['Tags'] = tag.text
```

**But its not working the print(tag) returns:**

```
<Element 'name' at 0x00000211BBEB0F98>
<Element 'tags' at 0x00000211BBEBD638>
```

Do you know how to get and sore the tags in the bands{}? For exemple in the exemple above the tags are rock, classic rock, irish, pop and alternative.

**The response have this format:**

```
<lfm status="ok">
<artist>
<name>U2</name>
<tags>
<tag>
<name>rock</name>
<url>https://www.last.fm/tag/rock</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>classic rock</name>
<url>https://www.last.fm/tag/classic+rock</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>irish</name>
<url>https://www.last.fm/tag/irish</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>pop</name>
<url>https://www.last.fm/tag/pop</url>
</tag>
<tag>
<name>alternative</name>
<url>https://www.last.fm/tag/alternative</url>
</tag>
</tags>

</artist>
</lfm>
```

**Minimal verifiable example:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests

ID = 1

api_key = "b088cbedecd40b35dd89e90f55227ac2"  # generated for the example

bands = {}

# GET TOP ARTISTS

artistslist = requests.get(
    'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettopartists&country=spain&page=1&limit=5&api_key=' + api_key)
tree = ET.fromstring(artistslist.content)
for child in tree:
    for artist in child.findall('artist'):
        name = artist.find('name').text
        bands[ID] = {}
        bands[ID]['ID'] = ID
        bands[ID]['Name'] = name

        ID += 1

# GET ARTIST INFO
for i, v in bands.items():

    chosen = bands[i]['Name'].replace(" ", "+")
    artist = requests.get(
        'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=artist.getinfo&artist=' + chosen + '&api_key=' + api_key)
    tree = ET.fromstring(artist.content)
    for child in tree:
        for artist in child:
            print(artist)
            for tag in artist.findall('tags'):
                print(tag['name'])
                bands[i]['Tags'] = tag.text
            if (artist.get('size') == "large"):
                if (artist.text is not None):
                    bands[i]['Image'] = artist.text

    print(bands[i]['Name'] + " RETRIEVED")
```

Comment: ...btw, this would be closer to complying with the **Minimal** part of [mcve] if you just hardcoded the smallest necessary subset of the response in your code -- that way folks don't need to either sign up for an API key themselves or hope that the one here is still valid.

Comment: (Similarly, there's no reason for the MCVE to include the code pulling the top artists if the problem is only in the code that gets details on an individual artist; even if you *were* going to query the public API, can hardcode just one artist name and remove the first loop entirely).

Answer (score 2):

In your loop, `artist.findall('tags')` returns a list with a single Element - the `<tags>` element. You are trying to iterate over each `<tag>` within the `<tags>` Element. Use the following instead:

```
for tag in artist.find('tags').findall('tag')
```

Also, note that `tag.text` is going to be `None`. Instead you probably want `tag.find('name').text` and `tag.find('url').text`.

Comment: Thanks, but like that it appears: <Element 'name' at 0x0000016DF79462C8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ozzy/PycharmProjects/getData/getData.py", line 19, in <module>
    for tag in artist.find('tags').findall('tag'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall' in "for tag in artist.find('tags').findall('tag'):"

Comment: The lines `for child in tree` and `for artist in child` will iterate over *all* children of their parent. Are you sure that this is what you want to do?

Comment: I want to store in a json file all artista info like this: {"ID": 0, "name": "U2", "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/U2", "tags": ["rock", "classic rock", "irish", "pop", "alternative"]}. Using xml it seems correct do like that, for the name and other data is working only tags dont work.